# url rewrite on locacl host on win7 :php

Tags: php

I tried to rewrite url from

```
products.php?id=1
```

to

```
product-1.html
```

i tried this in my localhost server 
and i am using wamp server on windows7

and this my htaccess file content

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]+)\.html$ products.php?id=$1
```

and this my products.php file content

```
<a href="products.php?id=1">show rewrite url</a>
```

my httpd.conf set from

```
 #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to

```
 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after that i restart wamp server 
but problem still appear and dosenot work

http://www.up.ma//uploads/images/up.macbeea0c9ed.png

Comment: So when you open this link what its give you ?[http://127.0.0.1/product-1.html](http://127.0.0.1/product-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing your links from:

```
<a href="products.php?id=1">show rewrite url</a>
```

to

```
<a href="product-1.html">show rewrite url</a>
```

mod_rewrite is done serverside, so you need to serve your intended links.

Comment: thanks its done but how i can convert all <a href="">  dynamically if is it possible @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: you could use ob_start() and ob_get_contents() on your output, then use dom or regex to convert all your links, but I would not advise this as its just easyier to convert as you go, the dynamic part is the `id` or `1` the rest its just markup.

Comment: thanks its done but how i can convert all <a href=""> dynamically if is it possible

Comment: also sometimes (99.9% of the time) its easier and more scalable to pass everything `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?request=$1` from rewrite to a controller that will handle the request else your .htaccess will grow from `RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]+)\.html$ products.php?id=$1` to a condition for every specific link change.